# Foreign Key column pointing to `craft_relations` table

Tags: plugin-development, relations, records

I am writing a plugin with a Record. I want the primary key of the table to also be a *foreign key* relating to the `craft_relations` table. Ordinarily, I would add something like this...

```
public function defineRelations()
{
    return array(
        'element' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, 'ElementRecord', 'id', 'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE),
    );
}
```

However, it seems like the `craft_relations` table **does not have a matching Record**.

How can I add a primary key column which is also a foreign key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't believe you'll be able to do that within the `defineRelations()` method – [Craft needs a record class for the table you want to create a relation with](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/records/BaseRecord.php#L565).

A workaround is to override the [`createTable()`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/records/BaseRecord.php#L239) method in your record class and add the foreign key constraint manually using [DbCommand](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/database):

```
public function createTable()
{
    parent::createTable();
    craft()->db->createCommand()->addForeignKey($this->getTableName(), 'id', 'relations', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
}
```

To be perfectly honest the above feels quite hacky and there might be a better way – but it seems to work :)

Comment: Yeah that's probably the best way for now 

Comment: Thanks Mats, that sounds like a solid workaround! (And thanks Brandon for confirming.)